# Calling a method from a different class containing Graphics g [JAVA]

Tags: java, graphics

im playing around with graphics and hit a bit of a roadblock. I can't seem to call my other class containing my graphics. Thanks in advance. As you can see i tried to call it as gameOBJ.Draw but its giving me errors.
This is the error:
The method Draw(Graphics) in the type GameObjects is not applicable for the arguments ()

```
public class Testing{

public boolean running = true;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameObjects gameOBJ = new GameObjects();
    gameOBJ.Draw();
    Window window = new Window(Window.WIDTH, Window.HEIGHT, Window.TITLE);
}






public class GameObjects{

public void Draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Window.WIDTH, Window.HEIGHT);

}
```

}

Comment: "its giving me errors" which ones? are you missing a closing bracket after Testing, or is this your actual code?

Comment: There is no function `Draw()` in class `GameObjects`.

Comment: Because  Draw(Graphics  g); want an object of type Graphics and in line gameOBJ.Draw(); you are not passing any object as argoment.

Comment: @CoveredEe i changed my gameOBJ.Draw(); to this gameOBJ.Draw(Graphics g); and it gives me this error Graphics cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: unrelated: please learn about java naming conventions, method names go camelCase(), so draw, not Draw!

Comment: You have to initialize an Graphics object first.  Graphics g = new Graphics(); (take a look to this object API to understand how it works) then try with gameOBJ.Draw(g);.

Comment: @GhostCat okay thank you for the advise!

Comment: @GhostCat I wont! nearly there just trying to understand some of the things posted.

Comment: @GhostCat Noted for future posts, thanks all for the help and advise!

Comment: You are welcome, and as said, you also now have the ability to say thanks by clicking these upward facing triangles on answers given to your questions ... hint hint ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix of that compilation error you can pass a `graphics` object.

For example you can use windows graphics (But this may not be the requirement of your task/project. With JDK 10 `Window.TITLE` is not present, I doubt if it was there in earlier versions as well.)

Optionally: By conventions method names in Java should start with small cases characters so the method name should be `draw`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameObjects gameOBJ = new GameObjects();

    //Pass the graphics object to the Draw method   
    Window window = new Window(Window.WIDTH, Window.HEIGHT, Window.TITLE);
    Graphics graphics =window.getGraphics() ; 
    gameOBJ.Draw(graphics);
}
```

Comment: Im not seeing any errors however im also not seeing my graphics when i run the program. Thank you for you time and help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
gameOBJ.Draw();
```

There:

```
public void Draw(Graphics g)
```

The method signature expects you to pass an argument, your invokation does not. Simply can't work that way.

The key thing here: you have to understand what you are doing: when your `draw()` method should draw "on something" then you have to pass that something to it, for example by first creating that window, to then fetch the graphics object belonging to the window.

Comment: Yes this makes sense, i know it has to pass an argument however everything i tried did work so i kept it clear to post here. Thank you :)